# Как закрыть в noindex один выпадающий пункт меню на WP?

Tags: wordpress

Возможно ли закрывать отдельные выпадающие меню через noindex?
Есть выпадающее меню, реализованое на отображение через функцию, т.е по одному я пункты уже закрыть не смогу.

```
  function custom_menu($name){
    wp_nav_menu( array(
        'theme_location'  => '',
        'menu'            => $name,
        'container'       => false,
        'container_class' => '',
        'container_id'    => '',
        'menu_class'      => '',
        'menu_id'         => '',
        'echo'            => true,
        'fallback_cb'     => '',
        'before'          => '',
        'after'           => '',
        'link_before'     => '',
        'link_after'      => '',
        'items_wrap'      => '<ul>%3$s</ul>',
        'depth'           => 0,
        'walker'          => '',
    ) );
}
function custom_mobile_menu($name){
    wp_nav_menu( array(
        'theme_location'  => '',
        'menu'            => $name,
        'container'       => false,
        'container_class' => '',
        'container_id'    => '',
        'menu_class'      => '',
        'menu_id'         => '',
        'echo'            => true,
        'fallback_cb'     => '',
        'before'          => '',
        'after'           => '',
        'link_before'     => '',
        'link_after'      => '',
        //'add_li_class'  => 'sub',
        'items_wrap'      => '<ul>%3$s</ul>',
        'depth'           => 0,
        'walker'          => '',
    ) );
}
```

В самом шаблоне оно выводится следующим образом:

```
<div class="desktop-menu">
                    <nav>
                        <?php custom_menu( 'Главное меню' ); ?>
                    </nav>
</div>
```

Нашла только способ как закрыть каждый пункт в nofollow через админ панель. В настройке меню отобразила у каждого пункта меню отношение к ссылке (XFN) и ввела там nofollow.
[image: https://photo-screen.ru/i/6v5xfALBS]
Но это не то что бы мне хотелось, все же мне нужен именно noindex.

Может кто подскажет где почитать или варианты каким образом не все меню закрыть, а только выпадающий список услуг?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вступление было лишнее, а скриншоты нужно в тело вставить. Исправь вопрос. И да. Не нужно без необходимости изобретать костыли и плодить сущности. Нужно учиться пользоваться предложенными инструментами. Есть меню в ВП - чем оно не устроило?

Comment: Исправила. Правильно? Дело не в самом меню, а в том что мне такой сайт уже пришел, с этим функционалом, переписать мне его нельзя, а вот закрыть в noindex необходимо, ищу реально ли такое при такой реализации.

Comment: Да, сейчас вопрос выглядит правильно. А переделывать костыли НУЖНО. Нужно уметь убеждать заказчика в этом. Это для его же блага и снижения расходов (и не только разовых, но и дальнейших) и разного рода рисков. Однако в данном случае это почти не костыли (не считая жёстково вывода меню в шаблоне) и никого ни в чём убеждать не нужно. Единственно правильный путь решения "проблемы" - это как раз в настройках меню указывать REL. На то это и CMS, а не самописька.